# turning a string representation of a nested list inside a list into a list

Tags: python, list

I need to turn

```
x = ["['born', '0', '15']", "['in', '2', '15']", "['a', '2', '15']", "['world', '3', '00']"]
```

into

```
x = [['born', '0', '15'], ['in', '2', '15'], ['a', '2', '15'], ['world', '3', '00']]
```

as it coded so that the first value of the nested list would be used as a name, the second value would be length in hours and third value is length in minutes.

Comment: `x = list(map(ast.literal_eval, x))`

Answer (score 0):

This is about how to convert string to list
You can try something as below

```
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(eval(i))
print(y)
```

output

```
[['born', '0', '15'], ['in', '2', '15'], ['a', '2', '15'], ['world', '3', '00']]
```